# Run Maven exec-maven-plugin with an option include dependencies with provided scope like Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, exec-maven-plugin

I would like to run a Main class with exec-maven-plugin with an option like "include dependencies with '**provided**' scope" from Intellij Idea. As I run the code with **exec-maven-plugin** I receive a lot of classNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError.
I am able to run successfully the Main class with the option "include dependencies with '**provided**' scope".

How could I run the main class from Maven or programatically without using the IDE ?

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>documentation-generator</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                        <mainClass>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: can you add the part of your pom related to dependencies ?

Comment: Why you want to included provided dependency, provided means it will be provided during runtime. Change it to compile if you want to include those dependencies

Comment: Try adding <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope> in plugin

Comment: This is a related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51481776/get-annotations-when-exec-maven-plugin-runs-main-does-not-work